# Does Cooper pairs only flow at surface at $T=0\rm K$? Then, how about at the temperature above 0K?

Tags: temperature, superconductivity

We know that Cooper pairs generate at critical temperature, and as more as reducing the temperature. But where are they? We also know them exhibit around Fermi surface as the wave-function. So, it means that cooper pair only appears near the superconductor surface? Can it be formed inside the superconductor?

Comment: Are you associating the Fermi surface with the actual physical surface of the superconductor?

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Yes, I think about Fermi surface associates to the surface of SC, is it correct?

Comment: The Fermi surface (FS) has no link to the physical surface of the material. The FS is the iso-energetic "surface" in reciprocal space with all the electrons that are at the Fermi energy. Because electrons are fermions, there is only one in a given state. So they fill states with increasing energy and the most energetic ones are at the Fermi energy. But, again, no relation between the FS and the material real space surface. Cooper pairs, form, exist, and travel away from the surface.